# Send text-box id to function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried to get the text-box's id via its event function but it seems `$a` doesn't work because the system understands this as text, what should I do?

```html
<select class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        class="dropdown-menu" 
        onchange="validateSelectBox(this,'skill_input4')">

<select class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        class="dropdown-menu" 
        onchange="validateSelectBox1(this,'skill_input3')">
```

```js
function validateSelectBox(obj, $a){
  
    var options = obj.children;
 
    var html = '';
 
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if (options[i].selected){
            html += options[i].value;
        }
    }
    // this is the error, the textbox does not change data
    // when I select the combobox
    document.getElementById('$a').value = html; 
}
```

Comment: Why two types of `class` in each select - Also where is the `textbox` ?

Comment: Can you kindly share a working fiddle? That will help us in understanding the problem statement.

Comment: remove quotes of $a : `document.getElementById($a).value`

Comment: `$a` that NOT right. Its `Javascript` not `PHP` => use simple `$a`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to put it in quotes as sting as it's a variable,Can you try this

```
document.getElementById($a).value = html;
```

Comment: Also, you can use just variable name such as $ instead of prefixing any variable name with $.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function validateSelectBox(obj, a)
{
  
    var options = obj.children;
 
    var html = '';
 
  
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if (options[i].selected){
            html += options[i].value;
        }
    }
document.getElementById(a).value = html; 
}
```

Comment: Please always consider leaving a comment on what you and why it solved the op's problem

Answer (score 0):

If skill_input3 and skill_input4  are the ids of the textbox as mentioned you should call
document.getElementById($a).value=html

Answer (score 0):

```
 function validateSelectBox(obj,$a)
{
  
    var options = obj.children;
 
    var html = '';
 
  
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if (options[i].selected){
            html += options[i].value;
        }
    }
document.getElementById($a).value = html;//remove '$a' from quotes.
}
```

> Remove'$a' From Quotes

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove $a from quotes as it a variable

```
function validateSelectBox(obj,$a)
{
  
    var options = obj.children;
 
    var html = '';
 
  
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if (options[i].selected){
            html += options[i].value;
        }
    }
document.getElementById($a).value = html;//remove '$a' from quotes.
}
```